# Why am I getting a "Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count" error when the data matches?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting the aforementioned error but my count on columns and data to insert are both 19

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO prescriptions (
        rxID, rxPrimeName, rxAltName, patient, prescriber, dpp, dppMetric, totalDailyDosage, 
        totalDailyPills, frequency, freqMetric, am, noon, pm, bed, prn, pharmacy, lastFill, pills
        )
    VALUES 
        (
        '$rxID', '$drugName1', '$drugName2', '$patient', '$prescriber', '$dpp', '$metric', '$totalDailyDosage,
        $totalDailyPills', '$quantity', '$frequency', '$am', '$noon', '$pm', '$bed', '$prn', '$pharmacy', '$lastFill', '$pills'
        )";
    $db->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$db = null;
```

Here is the exact error I'm receiving:

> INSERT INTO `prescriptions` ( `rxID`, `rxPrimeName`, `rxAltName`, `patient`, `prescriber`, `dpp`, `dppMetric`, `totalDailyDosage`, `totalDailyPills`, `frequency`, `freqMetric`, `am`, `noon`, `pm`, `bed`, `prn`, `pharmacy`, `lastFill`, `pills` ) VALUES ( '1111111', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Jordan', 'Test3', '50', 'mg', '100, 2', '1', 'BID', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'KJdh', '2022-04-15', '60' )
> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Both sides (`INSERT INTO` and `VALUES`) have 19

When I use phpMyAdmin to insert the data, here's what it comes back with:

> INSERT INTO `prescriptions` (`keyID`, `rxID`, `rxPrimeName`, `rxAltName`, `patient`, `prescriber`, `dpp`, `dppMetric`, `totalDailyDosage`, `totalDailyPills`, `frequency`, `freqMetric`, `am`, `noon`, `pm`, `bed`, `prn`, `pharmacy`, `lastFill`, `pills`) VALUES (NULL, '1234567', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Jordan', 'Test3', '30', 'mg', '60', '2', '1', 'BID', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'Atrium', '2022-04-15', '60');

*Please forgive the blocks on the column names above - I'm using `backquote` around the column names*

The phpMyAdmin one works perfectly **yes I'm aware that the variable data is different, but all acceptable types based on the column**

Comment: Assuming this code was copied correctly '$totalDailyDosage and $totalDailyPills' are one string, not two seperate parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I counted 18.
Looks like you are missing ' at '100, 2',

Comment: yup - you're right. I was missing one on the next line too. Apparently I need better glasses. I'll accept this when it lets me (5 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `values` clause is missing quotes:

```
VALUES 
(
'$rxID', '$drugName1', '$drugName2', '$patient', '$prescriber', '$dpp', '$metric',
'$totalDailyDosage, <-- missing quote before comma
-->> missing quote --> $totalDailyPills', 
'$quantity', '$frequency', '$am', '$noon', '$pm', '$bed', '$prn', '$pharmacy', '$lastFill', '$pills'
)";
```

Comment: You're definitely correct. The annoying thing is that I re-wrote this thing so many times and apparently made the same mistake over and over <head + desk>